# Is it possible to find the difference between two arbitrary text files using Git?

Tags: windows, git

These files are not necessarily version controlled.

I'm using Git and [Git GUI](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-gui) on [Windows XP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_XP).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, `git diff` works on two unversioned paths, both files and directories (recursive diff). I don't think you can do this from the GUI; you'll need to use the command line.

If you want GUI, I suggest installing [KDiff3](http://kdiff3.sourceforge.net/) instead. It can also be used by Git as a merge tool than if you set `diff.tool = kdiff3`, `diff.guitool = kdiff3` and `difftool.kdiff3.path =` *path-to-kdiff3.exe*

Answer (score 30):

You'll need to use the `--no-index` option unless one or both of the files are outside of a Git repository:

```
git diff --no-index path/to/file.txt path/to/other/file.txt
```

You can also use `git difftool` with the same arguments to invoke your GUI tool.

Answer (score 3):

In [Git Bash](https://superuser.com/questions/1053633/what-is-git-bash-for-windows-anyway) you can just use `diff file1 file2`.

Using [TortoiseGit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TortoiseGit), select both files, right click select TortoiseGit and click *diff*.

Comment: Tortoise git command line: `tgit /command:diff /path:C:\first.txt /path2:C:\second.txt`

Answer (score 3):

You can do that not only with [`git diff`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#Documentation/git-diff.txt-emgitdiffemltoptionsgt--no-index--ltpathgtltpathgt) (with `git diff --no-index -- file1 file2`), but now (Git 2.22, Q2 2019) again with `git difftool` too!
It was not possible for the past two years.

"`git difftool`" can now run outside a repository.

See [commit 20de316](https://github.com/git/git/commit/20de316e33446f37200e51aa333ba7d824dfd478), [commit 1a85b49](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1a85b49b87af0e17a503b94df10d0b39472ad5b8), [commit 1dcda05](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1dcda05820f1044a2ab35867c1fee1f829d2b92c) (14 Mar 2019) by [Johannes Schindelin (`dscho`)](https://github.com/dscho).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit b72e907](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b72e90712eb0e802b232ad4c88460d04279c7111), 25 Apr 2019)</sup>

> ### `difftool`: allow running outside Git worktrees with `--no-index`
>
> As far as this developer can tell, the conversion from a Perl script to
>   a built-in caused the regression in the difftool that it no longer runs
>   outside of a Git worktree (with `--no-index`, of course).
>
> It is a bit embarrassing that it took over two years after retiring the
>   Perl version to discover this regression, but at least we now know, and
>   can do something, about it.
>
> It fixes [`git-for-windows/git` issue 2123](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/2123).